# Why does Get-ChildItem -name return none if there is an escape character?

Tags: powershell, escaping, glob, get-childitem

I am searching for all files containing `(1)` in the name. Both these commands work:

```
ls -r *1* -name
ls -r *1`)*
```

But this doesn't:

```
ls -r *1`)* -name
```

Do you know why is that? I'm not sure if I miss something in the [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) doc

Comment: I can't reproduce it with PS `7.2.7` and `7.3.0-rc.1`. Works as expected and returns the files. Which version are you using (Check with `$PSVersionTable`). Furthermore, it's not good practice to use strings without quotes. With quotes you could remove the escape character ` and use `'*(1)*'` instead.

Comment: @swbbl 5.1.22000.832

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to work around your problem is actually the **conceptually simpler solution** to begin with: ***quote* your [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) pattern** (as a whole - if that doesn't help, see the next section):

```bash
ls -r '*1)*' -name # short for: Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path '*1)*' -Name
```

Note that, **unlike in POSIX-compatible shells such as Bash**, in PowerShell it is **perfectly fine to pass wildcard patterns as *single- or double-quoted strings***:

- Such patterns are *not* handled by *PowerShell itself* (the way the are in Bash, for instance), but by the *target command* (if supported). Therefore, the *syntactic form* used to pass them is *incidental* (unlike in Bash, for instance, where wildcard (globbing) patterns need to be *unquoted* in order to be treated as such).
- As such, arguments `*.txt`, `'*.txt'` and `"*.txt"` are *equivalent* in PowerShell, and are all seen as verbatim `*.txt` by the target command, which must then *itself* perform wildcard-pattern matching, as appropriate.
- While in POSIX-compatible shells such as Bash wildcard patterns are limited to matching *files and directories* based on *unquoted* patterns, **PowerShell's wildcard support - at least in the built-in cmdlets - is *generalized* and therefore *more versatile***:

  - Many parameters of built-in cmdlets support wildcard patterns even in *non*-file-system contexts.
  - For instance, [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object)'s `-Property` parameter allows matching *property names* by wildcard patterns, so that in the following example `-Property *Time` selects the `.CreationTime`, `.LastAccessTime` and `.LastWritTime` properties of the [`[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo) object output by `Get-Item`:

    ```bash
    Get-Item $PSHOME | Select-Object -Property *Time
    ```

---

As for **what you tried**:

- What you tried - *metacharacter-individual escaping* with `` ` `` (the so-called backtick, PowerShell's escape character) - *should* work.
- `` *1`)* `` *should* be the same as `'*1)*'`, i.e. a string with *verbatim* content `*1)*`, and its parsing is handled by PowerShell's *parameter binder*, *before* the target command sees it, so whether or not you also specify `-Name` shouldn't make a difference.
- If there is indeed a problem:

  - *Windows PowerShell*, the legacy, Windows-only, ships-with-Windows edition whose latest and *last* version is v5.1.x, is in *maintenance-only* mode and only *serious* bugs have a chance of getting addressed - and this one probably doesn't qualify.
  - By contrast, its modern successor, the cross-platform, install-on-demand [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) edition is actively maintained, so if you have a reproducible case using the latest stable version or one that is still officially maintained, I encourage you to report an [issue in the GitHub repo](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/new/choose).